# Serving gzipped html which is a merge of two gzipped that works on Chrome

Tags: node.js, performance, caching, gzip

I would like to have the top part of the page (from `<html>` until the `</head>`) in one shared gzipped file and the rest of the page separately, and serve them as one gzipped html document.

Note that [Chrome is not supporting multi member gzipped file](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=20884) (concatenated gzipped)

I can keep the files uncompressed, merge them and compress them in runtime, but that will hurt performance and it is a big issue here (we are caching billions of files)

How can I merge gzipped files without creating multi member file or serve html file that is comprised of two parts?

Is there any workaround for gzipping two files for Chrome?

Comment: This is still an issue...

Answer (score 0):

Try to use https://varnish-cache.org. It has ESI feature https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/tutorial/esi.html. So it probably do exactly what you want. As an additional plus, you also dont have to maintain you own caching software, because for decades of development there are already well developed products, that solves this.

Comment: We have 60TB of cached files. Not cost-effective to put that in memory.
Without enough memory, it falls back to the LRU, which means slow pages.